# In-memory API data not showing up when it should (not on first click/page load)

Tags: angular, typescript, in-memory-database

I just moved my data from mock data to in memory and everything seemed to be fine, except now when I click a button that should create various fields based on the data, they show up completely blank.

**app.module.ts**

```ts
import { BrowserModule }       from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule }            from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }         from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }          from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule }        from '@angular/router';

// Import for loading in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
// Important mock data from in memory service
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';


import { AppComponent }        from './app.component';
import { SimXesComponent}      from './simxes.component';
import { SimXComponent }       from './simx.component';
import { SimXDetailsComponent} from './simx-details.component';
import { SimXService }         from './simx.service';

import { AppRoutingModule }     from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SimXesComponent,
    SimXComponent,
    SimXDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    SimXService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**simx.component.html**

```html
<!-- SimutronX constructor: takes variables for creating a new Simutron instance -->
<h3>Create SimutronX</h3>
<form>
  <label for="SimX title">SimutronX Title</label>
  <input name="title" type="text" maxlength="2" placeholder="SimutronX" min="1" max="99"><br>
  <label for="coefficients">Number of {{coefficients.title}}</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="coefficients.value" name="coefficients" type="number" maxlength="2" placeholder="1" min="1" max="99"><br>
  <label for="constraints">Number of {{constraints.title}}</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="constraints.value" name="coefficients" type="number" maxlength="2" placeholder="1" min="1" max="99"><br>
  <button (click)="inputNums()">Submit</button>
</form>

<form *ngIf="valuesinput">
  <div>
    <label>Coefficient titles:</label>
    <li *ngFor="let slider of onedsliders">
      <input [(ngModel)]="slider.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Profit" ><br>
    </li>
    <label>Coefficient values:</label>
    <li *ngFor="let slider of onedsliders">
      <input [(ngModel)]="slider.value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" size="30" placeholder="0" ><br>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Constraint titles:</label>
    <li *ngFor="let slider of twodsliders">
      <input [(ngModel)]="slider.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Product Volume"><br>
    </li>
    <label>Upper boundries (max value)</label>
    <li *ngFor="let slider of twodsliders">
      <input [(ngModel)]="slider.max_value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Max Product" ><br>
    </li>
    <label>Lower boundries (min value)</label>
    <li *ngFor="let slider of twodsliders">
      <input [(ngModel)]="slider.min_value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Existing Orders" ><br>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Objective function title(s):</label>
    <li *ngFor="let output of outputs">
      <input [(ngModel)]="output.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Most Profit" ><br>
    </li>
  </div>
  <button (click)="createSimX()">Create SimutronX</button>
  <button (click)="createOneDSliders(5)">Test Button</button>
</form>

<!--  SimutronX instantiates here -->
<div *ngIf="simXcreated">
  <ul class="coefficients">
    <h3 class="header3" id="coefheader">{{coefficients.title}}</h3>
    <li *ngFor="let slider of onedsliders">
      <span class="onedslider">{{slider.id}}</span> {{slider.name}} = value: {{slider.value}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="constraints">
    <h3 class="header3" id="consheader">{{constraints.title}}</h3>
    <li *ngFor="let slider of twodsliders">
      <span class="twodslider">{{slider.id}}</span> {{slider.name}} = top value: {{slider.max_value}}, bottom value: {{slider.min_value}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="minmaxes">
    <h3 class="header3" id="minmaxheader">min/max</h3>
    <li *ngFor="let switch of switches">
      <span class="switch">{{switch.id}}</span> {{switch.name}} = state:
      <span *ngIf="switch.onoff" class="on"> on</span>
      <span *ngIf="!switch.onoff" class="off"> off</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="objectivefunctions">
    <h3 class="header3" id="objfuncheader">objective function</h3>
    <li *ngFor="let output of outputs">
      <span class="outputs">{{output.id}}</span> {{output.name}} = value: {{output.value}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**in-memory-data.service**

```ts
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { UIConstructor, s_OneDSlider, s_TwoDSlider, s_Switch, s_Output } from './gui';
import { SimX } from './simx';

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let simxes: SimX[] = [
    { id: 1, title: "Person Simulator",
      num_onedsliders: 3, num_twodsliders: 5, num_switches: 1,
      num_outputs: 1, onedslider_names: ["Herbert, Gwen", "Fred"],
      twodslider_names: ["Big Int", "Lead Reduction Variable",
      "Overhead", "Muscle Cramp", "Perculiarity Factors"],
      switch_names: ["Max/Min"],
      output_names: ["Profit"]
    },
    { id: 2, title: "Logistics",
      num_onedsliders: 2, num_twodsliders: 2, num_switches: 1,
      num_outputs: 1, onedslider_names: ["Kettlebells", 'Beans'],
      twodslider_names: ["Row Reduction", "Moon Phase" ],
      switch_names: ["Max/Min"],
      output_names: ["Objective Function"]
    }
  ];

  let s_onedsliders: s_OneDSlider[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Shipping Container Purchase Cost', value: 7, quantity: 9 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Container Rental Costs', value: 99, quantity: 15 }
  ];
  let s_twodsliders: s_TwoDSlider[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Available Shipping Containers', max_value: 99, min_value: 0, quantity: 3 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Purchasing Staff Available', max_value: 82, min_value: 0, quantity: 5 }
  ];
  let s_switches: s_Switch[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Min/Max', state: true }
  ];
  let s_output: s_Output[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Profit', value: 1000 }
  ];

  return {simxes, s_onedsliders, s_twodsliders, s_switches, s_output};
  }
}
```

**simx.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { UIConstructor, s_OneDSlider, s_TwoDSlider, s_Switch, s_Output } from './gui';
import { SimXService } from './simx.service';
import { SimX } from './simx';

@Component({
  selector: 'simx',
  templateUrl: './simx.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simx.component.css'],
  providers: [SimXService]
})

export class SimXComponent implements OnInit {
  simxes: SimX[];
  s_onedsliders: s_OneDSlider[];
  s_twodsliders: s_TwoDSlider[];
  s_switches: s_Switch[];
  s_outputs: s_Output[];
  valuesinput = false;
  simXcreated = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private simXService: SimXService) { }

  // Defines constructor values
  coefficients: UIConstructor = {
    id: 1,
    title: 'coefficients',
    value: 2
  }
  constraints: UIConstructor = {
    id: 1,
    title: 'constraints',
    value: 2
  }
  // Placeholders --  unhide hidden elements
  inputNums(): void {
    this.valuesinput = true;
  }
  createSimX(): void {
    this.simXcreated = true;
  }

  // Get all already created SimutronXes
  getSimXes(): void {
    this.simXService.getSimXes()
        .then(simxes => {
          this.simxes = simxes;
    });
  }



  /* Get GUI elements */
  getOneDSliders(): void {
    this.simXService.getOneDSliders()
        .then(sliders => {
          this.s_onedsliders = sliders;
    });
  }
  getTwoDSliders(): void {
    this.simXService.getTwoDSliders()
        .then(sliders => {
          this.s_twodsliders = sliders;
    });
   }
   getSwitches(): void {
    this.simXService.getSwitches()
          .then(switches => {
          this.s_switches = switches;
      });
   }
   getOutputs(): void {
     this.simXService.getOutputs()
         .then(outputs => {
           this.s_outputs = outputs;
     });
   }

   /* Create GUI elements in the DOM */
   createOneDSliders(num: number): void {
     for(let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       console.log(this.s_onedsliders);
       console.log(this.getOneDSliders());
     }
   }
   createTwoDSliders(num: number): void {
     for(let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       this.getTwoDSliders();
     }
   }
   createSwitches(num: number): void {
     for(let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       this.getSwitches();
     }
   }
   createOutputs(num: number): void {
     for(let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
       this.getOutputs();
     }
   }

}
```

**simx.ts**

```ts
export class SimX {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  num_onedsliders: number;
  num_twodsliders: number;
  num_switches: number;
  num_outputs: number;
  onedslider_names: Array<string>;
  twodslider_names: Array<string>;
  switch_names: Array<string>;
  output_names: Array<string>;
}
```

I tried running some console.log tests and the results were quite strange. When I first ran the test, (you can see the console.log statement in `simx.component.ts`) all of the in memory variables output as undefined. Yet when I clicked the button again, the output was `[object object]` and the details were of the in memory service data.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Just remarking that you should not name methods with a `get` prefix if they don't return a value.

Comment: Some of the methods aren't finished yet. I said I am utterly exhausted and haven't had energy to edit properly yet but it was edited out by a high rep user.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your service, but I assume now that you are using the in-memory web API that your retrieval methods are asynchronous.

I would assume that is why are you seeing it behave differently than with hard-coded data. The values *will* be undefined until they are retrieved.

I have an example of CRUD using the in-memory web API here if you are interested in an example: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms/tree/master/APM-Updated